# edit created_at field in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if its ok to edit the created_at value of a record in a DB in rails?

Best,
Elliot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change any of the fields but the primary key field, usually id, at any time. This includes created_at, or updated_at.

The created_at field is assigned before saving the first time, if not already set, and the updated_at field is adjusted each time the record is saved.